Как при чтении в файле, при необходимости, реализовать быстрый переход на начало новой строки?
Актуальность вопроса объясняется тем, что читаемая БД создавалась на мониторе и по-строчно. Функции, имеющиеся в арсенале С и С++ чтения в файле, не рассчитаны для этого случая(по-необходимости, быстрый переход на начало новой строки) или ещё  не известны мне, как и, возможно, макросы, если таковые есть. Фактически, здесь необходимо реализовать функцию/макрос, аналогичную управляющему символу '\n' (переход на начало новой строки), используемому для вывода на монитор и принтер.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

@aepot, я извиняюсь, но у меня проблемы с доступом на сам сайт stackexchange.com, где требуется осуществить вход, чтобы продолжить чат(он загружается), куда были перемещены комментарии отсюда! Как мне быть, ибо остались не выяснены некоторые нюансы?

Зайдите в свой профиль и завершите регистрацию учётной записи.

Ну что ж, попробуем так...
Если размер файла позволяет держать его целиком в памяти, то читаете его один раз в вектор строк.
Если файл слишком большой и не изменяется:
Прочитайте файл целиком один раз, составьте массив/вектор B[] индексов начал строк.
"Мама
 мыла
 раму" 
B: [0, 6, 12, 18]  
(для однобайтовой кодировки, с учётом переносов строк CRLF)

Затем при обращении к i-й строке прочитайте часть файла от байта B[i] до B[i+1]-1

справедливости ради - все [вот прям все] индексы на начала строк - не хранят, это бывает избыточно; т.е. хранят например каждый 10-ый [100-ый] индекс - и уже этого бывает достаточно, что бы весьма успешно лазить по тексту; зная [например] где находится [начинается] 10000-ая строка - весьма просто найти начало 10002-ой строки; это конечно же "к слову" написано, и всё зависит от конкретных задач, реализаций и требований; индексаторов напридумали столько, что все описать в принципе невозможно

@MBo, то, что предложили вы, является вариантом решения общей концепции, реализованной в массиве или контейнере, в частности, в векторе! Если в массиве можно реализовать, как на С, так и на С++, то в контейнерах(общий случай) - только на С++!

В общем смысле - эта проблема нерешаема, в случае если строки - переменной длины. Никто и ни что не может рассчитать в таких данных начало n-ой строки; даже кол-во строк рассчитать нельзя [но предсказать - можно]. Но задачу поиска начала конкретной n-ой строки - решить невозможно, нужен полный проход по всему файлу.
Однако же посмотрите на то, а вдруг ваша [не ваша] бд - выровнена? Это значит - каждая строка бд имеет фиксированный размер [в байтах]; если это так - тогда доступ к началу каждой строки прост:
p - начало n-ой строки
len - длина строки [в байтах] (исключая \r\n ?)
p = n * len + len(\r\n ?)

При этом, если бд - статическая [неизменяемая по времени/крайне редко изменяемая по времени/программно - неизменяемая по времени], то есть следующий смысл:

Выровняйте строки бд, и вышеизложенным способом вы найдёте начала нужных строк.

Если вы не хотите выравнивать строки, тогда соберите файл-индекс к этому файлу-бд и в виде файла положите рядом с файлом-бд. Т.е. в файле-индексе вы будете хранить список на начала каждой строки. Т.е. файл-индекс - это набор упорядоченных смещений на каждую строку, относительно начала файла, @MBo привёл пример, смотрите его пример.

Если вы добавляете в/удаляете из/изменяете в базе [надо полагать ручками] какие то данные, то эти данные нужно переиндексировать, т.е. пересоздать файл-индекс, где будут новые пересчитанные начала на строки. Т.е. для этого нужна маленькая микро-программка, которая запускается отдельно, вы внесли изменения в базу - переиндексируйте базу этой микро-программкой. Положите её рядом с файлом базы/файлом индексов.

Предсказать кол-во строк, и соответственно среднюю длину строки - можно, но это работает на более менее больших данных. И в вашем случае это ничего не даёт. Потому что вам не предсказания нужны, а конкретное число начала n-ой строки.

В случае если строки бд выровнены - смысл в разделителях отсутствует полностью. Однако же он нужен только с одной целью - что бы просматривать и редактировать бд любыми доступными способами через те самые "блокнотики".

Выравнивание бд работает строго байтами, а не чарами. Что такое чар - не известно. Вы можете видеть в блокнотике строку как набор чаров, но вы никогда не сможете сказать сколько байт в этой строке.

Учитывайте кодировку. Понятое дело тут utf-8 не подойдёт, но и с utf-16le/be нужно быть аккуратным, плюс имейте ввиду что некоторые блокнотики оставляют bom (byte order mark), т.е. это нужно учитывать, когда будете искать начала ваших строк.











Проблема не так проста как кажется, и если бы была проста, то давно бы имелись решения, причём множественные массовые решения.












Вы правы, что со строками равной длины решение задачи здорово упрощается и тогда не нужны разделители строк, но при этом здорово увеличивается итак большой файл БД и могут возникнуть проблемы с размещением в ОП(для наибольшей скорости) из-за её недостаточности + проблемы С/С++ из-за ручного управления ею! Я рассматривал это ранее и от этого подхода отказался! Да, и файл с индексами/адресами надо хранить тоже в ОП для скорости! А ещё в моём варианте предусмотрен, как вариант, последовательная запись индекса/адреса после конца каждой строки, кроме последней во время инициализации файла.

пишите ваше решение как ответ, и это нормально; есть идеи? озвучивайте; но весьма высока вероятность того, что найдутся грандиозные дыры, как в логике так и в производительности [привязке к железу - а без этого никак]

я написал комментарий к вашему решению и дополнил его своими соображениями на данный счёт с целью его улучшения, а можно делать это или нет я точно не знаю, ибо новичок, но хотел как лучше!
